# Crossfade animation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to loop through the code below and crossfade between them, but when my function runs I am only able to get one image to fade out and the rest are not doing anything, is there something wrong with my code, I am a noob in JS, the first image fades out and the rest just remain static, is there something I did wrong in my code.

```
HTML FILE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="./best1.png" alt="" class="image1 active" />
      <img src="./best2.png" alt="" class="image2" />
      <img src="./best3.png" alt="" class="image3" />
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
Javascript
const active = document.querySelector(".active");
const header = document.querySelector(".header");
console.log(header.firstElementChild);
// console.log(active);

function cycleImages() {
  console.log(active.nextElementSibling);
  let next =
    active.nextElementSibling.length > 0
      ? active.nextElementSibling
      : header.firstElementChild;
  next.style.zIndex = 2;
  // function fadeOut(el) {
  //   el.style.opacity = 1;
  //   (function fade() {
  //     if ((el.style.opacity -= 0.1) < 0) {
  //       el.style.display = "none";
  //     } else {
  //       requestAnimationFrame(fade);
  //     }
  //   });
  // }
  function fadeOutEffect() {
    // var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!active.style.opacity) {
        active.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (active.style.opacity > 0) {
        active.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        active.style.zIndex = 1;
        active.style.display = "block";
        active.classList.remove("active");
        next.style.zIndex = 3;
        next.classList.add("active");
        console.log(next);
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      }
    }, 200);
  }
  // setInterval(fadeOutEffect, 400);
  fadeOutEffect();
  // console.log(next);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setInterval(cycleImages(), 200));
// cycleImages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the actual opacity transition in pure CSS itself.

Therefore, all that's left to do on the JavaScript side, is decide whether a given element we want to cycle through, should be active, or not.

```js
// Get all matching elements, with class "cycleImage
const cycleImages = document.querySelectorAll(".cycleImage");

function cycle() {
  for (let i = 0; i < cycleImages.length; i++) {
    if (cycleImages[i].classList.contains('active')) {
      cycleImages[i].classList.remove('active');
      // If the new index we want to set to active is out of bounds, start back at the beginning
      const newActive = i + 1 >= cycleImages.length ? 0 : i + 1;
      cycleImages[newActive].classList.add('active');
      break; // If we have already encountered our solution, we can break out of the loop early.
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setInterval(cycle, 2000));
```

```css
.cycleImage.active {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cycleImage {
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  /* For test display only, remove from here */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.image1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.image2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.image3 {
  background-color: green;
}


/* Until here */
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="./best1.png" alt="" class="cycleImage image1 active" />
  <img src="./best2.png" alt="" class="cycleImage image2" />
  <img src="./best3.png" alt="" class="cycleImage image3" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,i really appreciate this.  this is an idea of the main thing I want to achieve in the link below:  looking at the section where we have the connect the influencers, I want to active animation like that, I really do not know how to go about it, any thoughts? thanks 
https://twitter.com/P_h_l_i_x/status/1353659923834544128

Comment: @Ogunleye It's appreciated to upvote the answer and accept if it answers the original question. If you have a new one, please post it. To give you a head start though, look more into CSS Transitions. I can achieve the desired effect using a similar approach to what I've provided, and CSS Transitions (hint: transform)

Comment: I voted the answer already, can you kindly show me how to come about that particular transition. The solution i came up with some mins ago uses an external library called anime Js and i can just move the elements out after the order, but can’t come up with my desired animation @cmprogram